# Stop text wrapping around image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a small personal project that I am working on and I can't seem to figure out how to make the text stop wrapping around the image when going from desktop size to mobile responsively

```html
<div class="text">​​​​​​​​ 
   <img src="/square.png" align="left" class="ms" alt=""/>
</div>
<div> 
   <span class="ms">Two paragraphs of text</span> 
</div>
```

Here is what it's doing now:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DY78.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03PNU.png)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77OJu.png)

I'd like for the text to shift to the bottom when it's shrunk to a certain width

Comment: You want to "stop the text wrapping around the image"... however the screenshots of what you want to do show exactly that. What do you want?

Comment: I'm just showing what it's doing, I apologize sol. I'd like for the text to shift to the bottom when it's shrinked to a certain width.

Comment: have u tried making the image `display:block` when in mobile view in your css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-> Please add following HTML & css code

-> Set image path in img tag

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .image, .text { clear: both; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" />
        <title> stop text wrapping around image </title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="file-path/test.jpg" align="left" class="ms" alt="image"/>
        </div>
        <div class="text"> 
            <span class="ms">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write css for mobile screen size (< 768 px), set value 100% for width style of image. Example, according to your code above:

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    .text {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thuan,

I ended up trying that and for some reason, it is still wrapping around the image. Is there possibly an alternative?